# AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "XYZ" among (_1,_2,_3)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In the following method I am trying to do some aggregating operation on an input Iterable and output a different Iterable pair. For that, I have created an RDD, defined the schema and then created the DataFrame from the RDD.

```
//Create a Row RDD
    val recordRDD = sc.makeRDD(tuples.toSeq).map(locTempRow)

    //Create the Schema for the DataFrame
    val schema = StructType(List(
      StructField("lat", DoubleType, nullable = true), //Latitude
      StructField("lon", DoubleType, nullable = true), //Longitude
      StructField("temp", DoubleType, nullable = true)))//Temperature

    //Create the DataFrame
    val recordDF = spark.createDataFrame(recordRDD, schema)
```

Then I am grouping on the latitude and longitude to get the average temperatures

```
//From DataFrame to group by lat and lon and avg on temp
    recordDF.map(r => (r.getAs[Double]("lat"),
                       r.getAs[Double]("lon"),
                       r.getAs[Double]("temp")
                       )).groupBy($"lat", $"lon").agg(avg("temp")).
                       rdd.map(agg => (Location(agg.getAs[Double]("lat"), agg.getAs[Double]("lon")), agg.getAs[Double]("temp"))).collect()
```

I am getting this exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "lat" among (_1, _2, _3);
```

I tried adding $ before the column string literals, removing $ from all of them, but the error is still the same.

The printSchema() shows this correctly:

```
root
 |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |-- lon: double (nullable = true)
 |-- temp: double (nullable = true)
```

Where's the problem, when I can clearly see that there are lat, lon and temp columns why in groupBy call, its failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `map` function. You convert your data to `Tuple3[Double, Double, Double]` which obviously has no `lon` or `lat` fields. It is also very inefficient.

Instead just:

```
recordDF.groupBy($"lat", $"lon").agg(avg("temp"))
```